# Why don't sql databases allow creating functions for all queries vs constructing the sql strings in the calling program?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

I'm new to sql and rdbms, and just curious why sql database drivers (e.g. postgreSQL, mySQL, etc) for languages like python, node, c#, etc, require you to programmatically construct the query strings in the language rather than calling a database function for all queries? Wouldn't it be a better level of abstraction to write all the queries in the database and call those functions from the code?

Why do this (pseudo code):

```
var query = "select * from " + table_name + ";"
```

When you could just do something like this:

```
var rows = dbInstance.getAll(table_name, max_rows, start);
```

Wouldn't it be less clunky and higher performance if the queries were constructed in the database itself?

Comment: Aren't you just suggesting syntactic sugar ( actually, a syntactic stick )? What you effectively suggest is to transform a full-fledged query language (SQL) into an API of  parameterized functions. I fail to see that you win in abstraction, in particluar for more complicated queries than toy examples that would involve subqueries, joins, aggregation etc. Add to these thoughts that SQL is closely linked to relational algebra which is already a well-defined mathematical foundation at a rather high level of abstraction.

Comment: @u84six . . . SQL queries are so much more powerful than this.

Comment: @collapsar You win not having to construct really complicated query strings in a non sql language and then calling it from client code. Whereas, you could just write the complicated query in the database and label it to be called from the calling program.

Comment: You're also always welcome to write your own custom defined functions if you plan on reusing some queries with just different parameters.  But like @collapsar said, given how most people don't just need a `SELECT *`, its better this way.

Comment: In some cases there may be certain elements of the business logic that can be usefully coded as database functions.  However, in many cases day-to-day database management involves writing queries (up to hundreds or thousands of lines long) that will be executed only once; there is no benefit to storing these in the database.

Comment: @bjk116 I'm still not convinced. If people want complex queries, just write in at the db level and then expose it to calling programs.

Comment: @u84six The performance would not significantly improve (if at all) as the composition of API functions and/or the structure of arguments with complex data types would need to be validated and turned into an execution plan in the DB anyway. If you plan to basically provide a single API function for each 'kind' of query (withiout giving thoughts to what 'kind' would exactly mean here) you cripple the query space to being effectively unusable in real-world settings.

Comment: @u84six I tried doing what you said before and very shortly you will find it is much easier to just write your queries in strings.

Comment: @rd_nielsen so there's no performance benefit for really complex queries if they're built at the db level?

Comment: @u84six You should also consider that SQL is standardized to a large extent. Who should standardize the API you are envisioning? If you don't standardize, I place a bet that each vendor will develop their own 'superior developer experience' ...

Comment: @bjk116 I'm not sure what you mean by "easier". Wouldn't it be less work to just use the sql language at the db level to write the function, then expose to the calling program?

Comment: The query plan for a query embedded in a stored function is not cached.  It must be re-evaluated every time the function is run.  So, no.

Comment: @rd_nielsen ok, so now I'm getting some answers. If there's no performance gain, then I can see why people don't do this. It just seems really tedious to have to construct these complex queries when you could just write it using its native language.

Comment: @u84six Well say you're editing your code and realize you need to modify your function to a different situation.  Now 1) You have to open up your DB workbench and 2) any other place that uses that function might get messed up. 3) Or your function is going to turn into a bunch of IF ELSE statements for different scenarios and that will be more of a hassle to maintain.

Comment: @bjk116 well that's not very convincing. That problem goes with any language, any library. People should take care in making their code backwards compatible, or at least, version control it. So that's not really a big issue.

Comment: @u84six Honestly, go for it.  Experience is the best teacher.

Comment: @u84six I do not see in which way your API would be easier to use. If you wrap complex queries into simple function calls in an ad hoc way, how do you organize the the plethora of your API? How do you document the API?

Comment: @u84six Another aspect: What is the purpose of using 'native' idioms to interact with the DB if the paradigm of the native language is actually incompatible with the conceptual framework of a DB? Example: A relational DB basically is about set manipulation which is at odds with most imperative and OO languages (see the mention of ORM mappers in Bill Karwin's answer)

Comment: Well you're all convincing me that it's a bad idea, and that's what I was looking for. I'm not arguing. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many libraries that give you a more object-oriented usage of database queries. For example:

- [jOOQ](https://www.jooq.org) for Java apps
- [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org) for Python apps
- [Doctrine](https://www.doctrine-project.org) for PHP apps
- [ActiveRecord](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) for Ruby apps

These are usually called ORM libraries. ORM means Object-Relational Mapping, because relational databases are not object databases, and these libraries have to fetch rows of data and *map* them onto collections of objects in your app. And then vice-versa, when you save objects, it maps them into rows of data.

These ORM libaries make your code look nicer, and for certain tasks you may be able to write code more productively, but ORMs don't make queries run any faster in the database. On the contrary, complex ORMs like Hibernate are notorious for translating your code into inefficient SQL, and making the queries have much worse performance.

The queries still run in the database server regardless of how you invoke them. The majority of time is spent in the database, not in your app.

And yet ORM packages fail to support the power of SQL. SQL is a language itself, and it can do things that are very awkward to represent in code like you show, that only uses objects and functions. The example you show of getting all columns for all rows from a single table is fine for an ORM. ORM's generally do well for simple CRUD (create, read, update, delete) code that works with individual rows of a single table, mapping them into collections of objects in your app.

ORM packages that try to simulate a greater variety of SQL queries end up being incredibly difficult to learn and to use. The code for Hibernate is 800,000 lines of Java.

You might also like to read https://hackerfall.com/story/what-orms-have-taught-me-just-learn-sql

Comment: I can see how this is all playing out now. And I've just looked around and noticed that there are libraries that assist in creating sql queries (string based) rather than subjecting to ORMs.

Comment: Yes, there are "helper" libraries that you can use to format valid SQL more reliably. But they don't support 100% of SQL syntax, and they are hard to use for complex SQL. Still, they're good to use for simple queries.

Comment: I'm also suspected that because of the nature of this tediousness, people tend to use no sql databases these days so that everything is app driven.

Comment: NoSQL can only do relatively simple queries, and there's no guidance on how to organize the data in your database. Inevitably, when you store data in NoSQL, you favor some queries at the expense of others. Relational databases designed to conform to rules of normalization support the broadest variety of query types, and also it's not possible to create data anomalies.

Comment: MongoDB is an example of a NoSQL database that does support more complex queries. Read this page and see if you think it's any simpler than learning SQL: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/map-reduce/

Comment: I've done some Mongo stuff in the past. But while it seemed really easy to use at the app level, designing the documents was a bit of a challenge. You definitely need to think differently when it comes to "relational" data.

Comment: A paintbrush is really easy to use, too. Therefore it's easy to paint a portrait, right? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ecce_Homo_(Mart%C3%ADnez_and_Giménez,_Borja)

Comment: I definitely agree with you there. ;)